# Connect to a Firestore database other than the default from Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to connect to a Firestore database other than the default one from a JavaScript-implemented GCP Cloud Function. I've seen some possible solutions using the Firebase library, but in my case, I'm using "@google-cloud/firestore": "^6.7.0" directly. I've tried it like this:

```js
const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: "my-gcp-project",
  database: "my-db"
});
```

However, it connects to the default database. How can I specify the database?

Comment: Try ```databaseId``` and not ```database```

Comment: thnaks, with databaseId worked

Answer (score 0):

The [source code for the Settings object](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/47768485c1c5502ed9c7471501a809a252046b6c/types/firestore.d.ts#L242) you pass to the Firestore constructor says that the property to specify the name of the database (if not the default) is [databaseId](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/47768485c1c5502ed9c7471501a809a252046b6c/types/firestore.d.ts#L255) (not "database").

Comment: yes, it worked, thanks